# EJB Exception: : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/MySQLConnection

Tags: java, jax-ws, oracle-adf, weblogic-10.x, oracle-adf-mobile

I am Creating web-service using ADF JEE web application. When I was trying to access web-service it's throwing exception. I place **mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin** jar in my project class path and **C:\Users\PC2\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.4.39.64.36.1\DefaultDomain\lib** also but it throwing exception like below.

**Exception**

```
EJB Exception: : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/MySQLConnection
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:630)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:614)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:305)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:246)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
```

Thank you

I Overcome from this exception Now another exception raised

**Exception**

```
 javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to receive message. caused by: 
 java.io.IOException: null caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException:  
 javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Premature end of file encountered caused by:  
 javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Premature end of file encountered
```

Comment: Is the jar on the weblogic classpath ?

Comment: yes I put the jar in bin folder of weblogic server

Comment: you can add the jar to the $DOMAIN/lib or you can go the manual route and add the jar to `CLASSPATH` variable of the `startWebLogic` command, based on the above i'm assuming windows C:\WebLogic_install_directory\user_projects\domain_name

Comment: @KennethClark I added mysql...jar to jre/bin/ext folder.Now another exception raised When I am trying to call web service. Exception I will add to my post now. Thank you

Comment: This can be caused by the response, check that you are generating a well formed xml response